# Simple scopes and association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm new to scopes, and don't really understand them well.Let's say I have 2 models, `Project` and `Ticket`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
end
```

I'm used to code like this to access associated data from tickets:

```
Project.find(1).tickets.each do |ticket|
 puts ticket.name
end
```

I created new scope:

```
scope :default, -> { where(default: true) }
```

And now when I use `Project.default` I get back `ActiveRecord::Relation` and don't have a clue how to access associated `tickets` ?

Comment: @DaveNewton what would you use? lambdas are default way to proceed in Rails 4 I think

Comment: @apneadiving I guess I still prefer class methods; it's listed as a preference in the Rails docs, and preferred when there are arguments--I like keeping them all the same, YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand your point of view, I usually use lambdas because I like the `scope` method which makes things very clear (for me!)

Comment: @apneadiving Yeah, `scope` is much more self-documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project.default will indeed return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which is a 'to be triggered' query. The query will be triggered once you start looping etc, this is sort of transparent to you.

If you want to get tickets from the projects, first I recommend you include them in your query to avoid N+1. Do it this way:

```
projects = Project.default.includes(:tickets)
```

Then to access tickets of a particular project:

```
project = projects.first
project.tickets
```

---

If you want a method to always return a single object:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets

  def self.get_default_with_tickets
    Project.where(default: true).includes(:tickets).first
  end
end
```

then:

```
Project.get_default_with_tickets #=> your_project
```

Be sure to handle the cases:

- when there is more than one match
- when there is no match

Comment: my default scope is expected to return only one Project, so I hoped to avoid having to write project = project.first and instead return directly that record, but I assume that's not possible with scopes ?

Comment: no, scopes are supposed to filter collections. write a class method if you want, let me edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

A [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) is basically just a [class method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) (one which fires on a non-intialized model):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tickets
 scope :defaults, -> { where(default: true) }
end
```

This means if you do this:

```
@defaults = Project.defaults
```

... you get all the `project` objects back which have the attribute `default` as true

This is the same as this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tickets
 def self.defaults
      where(default: true)
 end
end
```

---

**Error**

The reason you're getting a relation is because when you use `where`, you're basically getting back an "array" of data (as opposed to just a single record). If you `.each` through the data or just return `.first`, you'll get an actual object which you can output:

```
@defaults = Project.defaults
@defaults.each do |project|
    project.tickets #-> associated tickets
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `all` or `first` to complete the query.

```
#get all default projects
Project.default.all 

#get the first default project
Project.default.first
```